# AngularJS : Load additional template in custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have an Angular custom directive which uses a very simple carousel template which only has 2 slides loaded and bound because I expect to repeat lots of them on a page. When the user interacts with the directive I want to load an additional template containing the rest of the slides and compile it under the same scope as everything else in the directive.

This is how I am doing it so far. This function is inside my directive and is called when the user clicks the "next" button.

```
function loadExtraSlides(){

    $templateRequest('/templates/propertyCardExtraSlides.tpl.html').then(function(template) {
        $compile($(carouselEl).append(template).contents())($scope);
              // Template is loaded
            }, function() {
                $log.error('Error loading card slides template');
            });

        }
    }
}
```

This seemed to work at first because the template is loaded and inserted inside the carousel, but unfortunately the new template isn't bound to the scope correctly. If I put {{images}} into the main template is outputs an array of image URLs from my directive's scope. If I put the same thing in my template which is being imported and compiled it just outputs "{{images}}" to the DOM.

Hopefully I'm doing something simple wrong. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why you need to do any of this. Seems like an `nf-if` on an `ng-include` would probably meet your needs. Explain more about user interaction and data model for this directive

Comment: You may be right about that. I will give it a go. I didn't want to use ng-include because I didn't want the extra HTML loaded and compiled against the scope until the user clicks the next button on the carousel, but an ng-if might solve this problem if the include doesn't happen until the ng-if is satisfied.

Comment: You're a genius. If you make than an answer I'll mark it correct and upvote it. It would still be interesting to find out why my code above didn't bind the new html to the scope of the directive which was passed to it, but I have a solution for now. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you are thinking too much with a jQuery hat on and not an angular one